# cURL-Is there any way to force curl to use a specific net interface

Tags: android, c++, http, curl, libcurl

If I have different ways of net connections like wifi, cell data in my android phone, Is there any way to tell cURL to use a specific interface while connecting to the server and not to use any other if available. I only want to connect using wifi and do not want to use cell data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the --interface option. From the curl man page:

> --interface
>
> Perform an operation using a specified interface. You can enter
>   interface name, IP address or host name. An example could look like:
>
> curl --interface eth0:1 https://www.example.com/
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.

Comment: Thanks vielmetti, that mapped to CURLOPT_INTERFACE.